# My server is getting high traffic and reaches his limits, what should be my new structure?

Tags: php, server, webserver, apache2, traffic

**Current config:**

16GO RAM, 4 cpu cores, Apache/2.2 using prefork module (which is set at 700 maxClients, since avg process size ~22MB), with suexec and suphp mods enabled (PHP 5.5).

Back-end of site using CakePHP2 and storing on a MySQL server. The site consists of text / some compressed images in the front and data processing in the back.

**Current traffic:**

~60000 unique visitors daily, on peaks I'm currently easily reaching 700+ simultaneous connections which fills the MaxClients. When I use `apachectl status` at those moments, I can see that then all the processes are used.

The CPU is fine. But the RAM is getting all used.

**Potential traffic**:

The traffic might grow to ~200000 unique visitors daily, or even more. It might also not. But if it happens, I want to be prepared. Since I've already reached the limits of the current server using that config.

So I think about taking a new server, much bigger, like with 192GB Ram and 20 cores for example.

I could keep exactly the same config (which means I would then be able to handle 10* my current traffic with that same config).

But I wonder if there is a better config in my case using less ressources and being as much efficient ? (and which is proved to be so)

Comment: Additional information request. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: No SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server. Here is the paste bin with the information you asked: https://pastebin.com/0GA7R3yi I've already done some MySQLTuner recommendations in the past, and just realised the file per table is still OFF because to turn it ON I would have to dump and reset everything. `sysstat` is not installed on that server, so can't `iostat` in its current state.

Comment: Thanks for your data.  Any chance of getting Perl script from mysqltuner.com and posting a complete report?  It would help with know more about your system, table count and data size by engine.  Analysis is in process.

Comment: Here it is: https://pastebin.com/PHgZVerq

Answer (score 0):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section,

```
thread_cache_size=100  # from 8 to reduce threads_created 
innodb_io_capacity=500  # from 200 to allow higher IOPS to your HDD
read_rnd_buffer_size=128K  # from 256K to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 129,942
thread_concurrency=6  # from 10 to expedite query completion with your 4 cores
slow_query_log=ON  # from OFF to allow log research and proactive correction
```

These changes will contribute to less CPU BUSY.

Observations: 
A) 5.5.54 is past End of Life, newer versions perform better.
B) These suggestions are just the beginning of possible improvements, even with 5.5.4.
C) You should be able to gracefully migrate to innodb_file_per_table once 
you turn on the option.  Your tables are already managed by the innodb engine.

For additional assistance including free downloads of Utility Scripts, view my profile, Network profile, please.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendations. The CPU used by mysql is actually pretty fine, it takes mainly a few percents. But it's always good to optimize. I have a few questions still. A/ Do you know how can I significantly reduce the AVG apache2 process size ? B/ Do you think it would be a good idea to migrate to `PHP-fpm` with `mpm_event_module` instead of `prefork` ? C/ If so, how much might it help ?

Comment: For your A) not my area of expertise B) not acquainted with the process C) I do not know.  MySQL server tuning is my focus.

Comment: @Leo Have you had an opportunity to apply the suggestions?  Please provide feedback - positive or negative.  Thanks

Comment: Hi Wilson. Thank you for your suggestions on `mysql`, I didn't do those changes yet because `mysql` is running pretty smoothly atm on the production and takes only ~2% CPU. I already fined it using `MySQLTuner` some time ago which I guess handle the big lines of the conf side. And I already worked on slow queries on the other side. But I take in account your suggestions in case I need them later.

Comment: And about `You should be able to gracefully migrate to innodb_file_per_table once you turn on the option. Your tables are already managed by the innodb engine`, the fact is that it is set on `on` in the `mysql.conf`, and even now when I restart it's still `off` :/ `innodb_file_per_table = ON` `innodb_log_file_size = 1G`  in `[mysqld]` section of `my.cnf`

Comment: @Leo  My apologies, with MySQL 5.5.54 in the config = 1 may be required on this old version.  Stop/restart then check value with SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_file_per_table';  Is your system running quicker with the suggestions?

Comment: Should I have to stop & backup all the db before that ? Would it be really better with one file per table ? (just 2 tables are mainly used, and both have more than millions rows). I switched mpm_prefork to mpm_worker on apache2, and it is doing better than before. While still using most of the RAM.

Comment: @Leo  BEFORE you change file per table, additional information request. 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
df -h  for a Linux/Unix free space list by device, 
   includes hda & sda (SSD) filesystem type clues. 
free -h  for a Linux/Unix Total Used Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
for server workload tuning analysis.

Comment: I searched on internet why `innodb_file_per_table` should be turned `ON` and some people choose to keep it since you can loose performance. It depends of the database. In my case I have almost only one or two huge tables which are used. So I'm not sure if it is necessarily a good idea to change that variable.

Comment: When you need to manage Free Space in your tables, you will have a more difficult time completing the task than when you use innodb_file_per_table=1 for your data storage.  It is just a matter of how long it takes for page splits to build up over time. If our suggestions were of any improvement, please consider an upvote or accept and let us all know how much better your equipment is running. Thanks